# What do the different icons beside Xcode projects mean?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I open Xcode, it prompts me to open recent projects. In the screenshot below, the second and third projects are the same, and the first is different.

**What I Want To Know:**

1) What is the difference between the white and blue Xcode icons at the left?

2) Given the the second and third projects are the same, one has a white icon and the other has a blue icon. What does it mean for them both to be listed?

[image]

Comment: My mistake, it's attached now.

Comment: You should close that splash screen and tell Xcode not to display it again. It’s just annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white icons are Xcode workspaces (`.xcworkspace`) and the blue icons are Xcode projects (`.xcodeproj`). A workspace can refer to one or more projects.

Here are examples of three different Xcode document types from my Open Recents menu:

[image: menu showing an Xcode playground, an Xcode workspace, and an Xcode project]

Comment: Ok thanks. For the second and third files (one white one blue), they both have the same `<project path>/ios` pathname. Would the workspace and project both be referenced by the same path?

Comment: They have different filename extensions, but Xcode is hiding the extensions.

Comment: If instead of clicking the workspace or project, I manually open the ios folder, do you know if that opens the workspace or project?

Comment: Probably it opens the workspace but I haven't investigated.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between the white and blue Xcode icons at the left?

The blue ones are project files and the white ones are workspaces. Workspaces can refer to several project files, which makes them useful for working with several different components at once. For example, you have a project that builds a framework and another that builds a test application that uses the framework. Using a workspace lets you work on both at once.

> Given the the second and third projects are the same, one has a white icon and the other has a blue icon. What does it mean for them both to be listed?

It simply means that you can open any of them. Note that you can't have the same project open more than once, so if you open a project and then open a workspace that refers to that project, you won't be able to see the contents of the project in the workspace.

Comment: Actually, Re "you won't be able to see the contents of the project": so you open Project A and then open Workspace A which contains Projects A B and C, in Workspace A you'd see Projects B and C but not A?

Comment: You'll see Project A in Workspace A also, but you won't be able to see Project A's contents in Workspace A. You can either go work in Project A (since you have it open), or you can close it. Can't remember if you need to close and reopen the workspace or not -- try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

The white icon represents a Xcode workspace, which has an extension of `.xcworkspace`. The blue one is for xcode project with an extension of `.xcodeproj`.

An Xcode workspace can contain multiple projects.

> A workspace is an Xcode document that groups projects and other documents so you can work on them together. A workspace can contain any number of Xcode projects, plus any other files you want to include. In addition to organizing all the files in each Xcode project, a workspace provides implicit and explicit relationships among the included projects and their targets.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html